# Subclassing the Django ImageFileField

Tags: python, django, image, django-models, metadata

I'm interested in subclassing django's ImageFileField to allow access to the image IPTC metadata, something like:

```
>>> from myapp.models import SomeModel
>>> obj = SomeModel.objects.all()[0] # or what have you
>>> obj.image.iptc['keywords']
('keyword','anotherkeyword','etc')
```

... the [docs say](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#a-few-suggestions) to [read over django's internal code](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L280), which I did; I've tried to produce a working implementation and I am not sure what I'm doing -- I've defined custom fields before, but I can't come up with boilerplate setup for a file-based field.

I know I need to define an `attr_class` and a `descriptor_class` to make it work. Does anyone have a straightforward example or suggestion, with which I could get started?

Comment: NB: I'm not asking how one implements something like my example; I just need to know how to set up whatever the requisite subclasses are for a custom field in aid of such an implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear from your question: have you tried something like this?

```
class ImageMetadataMixin(object):
    """Mixin can be added to any image file"""
    @property
    def iptc(self):
        """Or something like this"""

class ImageWithMetadataFieldFile(ImageMetadataMixin, ImageFieldFile):
    pass

class ImageWithMetadataField(ImageField):
    attr_class = ImageWithMetadataFieldFile
```

I think it's all what necessary. Why do you think you need to redefine `descriptor_class`?

Comment: wow, that is nice and succinct -- I am going to try that toot sweet, thx.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I have figured this one out -- thanks in part to the answer @valya provided. An example of a successful implementation can be found in my fork of django-imagekit:

https://github.com/fish2000/django-imagekit/blob/icc-develop/imagekit/modelfields.py