# Extract Image Metadata in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, metadata

I am trying to extract EXIF and XML data from many different types of images- JPG, PNG, etc. I am defining a class named `image` in my `models.py` file as follows:

```
class image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='directory/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, help_text="Descriptive image title")
    meta = #?
```

How do I extract the metadata and include meta with my models?

Comment: Is this link helpful solving this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973586/subclassing-the-django-imagefilefield

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def get_exif(fn):
    ret = {}
    i = Image.open(fn)
    info = i._getexif()
    for tag, value in info.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        ret[decoded] = value
    return ret
```

Comment: How would this be implemented into a models.py?

Comment: You assign the return value to your 'meta' field. Isn't that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Exactly. Let me know if it works, and if that's the data you wanted