# Preserve image metadata in Django upload form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, metadata

I want to extract metadata from images that are uploaded using a form. Right now it seems that metadata is overwritten/removed.

I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637170/extract-image-metadata-in-django) question, but the answer provided in that thread is lacking in where that code should be and why. Using that in my view gave nothing.

Here's my current model:

```
class signUp(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
sex = models.CharField(max_length=1)
dob = models.CharField(max_length=10)
image = models.FileField(upload_to='images')
```

### EDIT:

This is my current view. Don't know how it should help, but here you go.

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = signupForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        result = form.instance

        [removed irrelevant code]

        if error:
            return render(request, 'main.html', {'form': form, 'result': result, 'error': error})
        return HttpResponse(1)
    
else:
    form = signupForm()
return render(request, 'main.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Can you share your current view?

Comment: Can you make sure that the indentation of your code in the first code snippet is correct?

Comment: Yes, the indentation is fine. The form works and I can see the images that are uploaded, the problem is that the METADATA gets removed during the process. The form itself is perfectly fine.